# Как скрыть ссылку в нижнем углу страницы?

Tags: javascript, jquery, thymeleaf

Подскажите пожалуйста!
Формирую ссылку следующим образом

```
<td><a th:if="${tab[5] != null}" th:href="@{/file/(fpath=${tab[5]}, fname=${tab[6]} )}" target="_blank">Просмотр</a></td>
```

При наведении на нее в левом нижнем углу ссылка отображается в явном виде. Есть ли способы ее скрыть?

Comment: Нет. Зачем это может быть нужно?

Comment: А если вы перейдете по ссылке, то вы ее увидите в явном виде в строке браузера.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ссылку можно скрыть используя `JavaScript` функцию в `onclick` event. Ваш код может выглядеть примерно так (извените, если есть ошибки, я его не запускал)

```
<script>
    function preview(elem) {
        var windowOptions = "location=no,height=500,width=800,scrollbars=yes,status=yes";
        window.open(elem.getAttribute("data-url"), '_blank', windowOptions);
    } 
</script>

// ...

<td><a onclick="preview(this);" href="#" th:if="${tab[5] != null}" th:data-url="@{/file/(fpath=${tab[5]}, fname=${tab[6]} )}">Preview</a></td>
```

jQuery код ...

```
<script>
    $("a[name='preview']").click(function(event) {
        event.stopPropagation();
        var windowOptions = "location=no,height=500,width=800,scrollbars=yes,status=yes";
        window.open($(this).data('url'), '_blank', windowOptions);
    }); 
</script>

// ...

<td><a name="preview" href="#" th:if="${tab[5] != null}" th:data-url="@{/file/(fpath=${tab[5]}, fname=${tab[6]} )}">Preview</a></td>
```